# Windows Azure Virtual Network (Vnet) popup is not showed anymore

Tags: windows-10, vpn, azure

I'm trying to understand why my Azure VPN stops to work. I installed the Azure VPN using a `.exe` executable file (`VpnClientSetupAmd64.exe`) provided by the cloud administrator months ago, with a certificate (`p12` file) generated for me.

To connect to the Azure VPN, I accessed the Windows VPN networks (Configuration > Network > VPN), selected the Azure VPN (installed by the executable) and clicked on "Connect". After that a popup like this appears:

[image]

But this popup **is not showed anymore**.

The main suspect is a recent windows update: https://www.tachytelic.net/2019/06/vpn-connections-not-working-windows-10-1903-update , because few days ago everything was working:

> I received the latest Windows 10 update today (May 2019 – Build 1903) and found that none of my existing VPN connections worked.

The workaround not work for me:

> 1. Create a new shortcut on your desktop to:
>
>    ```
>    C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe
>    ```
> 2. Try your VPN connection.

When I click on "Hang up", the "Network connections" popup is closed and opened again. Nothing more happens.

I already faced similar problem when I tried to connect to the VPN using some non admin user. But is not the case now, my user is an admin.

So, what could I do to understand what is the problem? There is an alternative to connect to the Azure VPN? I saw some tutorials to create the VPN from "scratch", using the files inside the Azure VPN executable (`cmroute.dll`, `routes.txt`, etc) but it's a lot of work and some steps are unclear.

Comment: Can you download the package again from the Portal and install again and check if that works?

Comment: @msrini-MSIT I'm trying to do that, because I need to make a request for the responsible area (I don't have the necessary permissions to do myself). But this will take some days.